# Running an local executable/binary via a web app?

Tags: browser, plugins, web-applications, npapi, google-nativeclient

Extending a web app for someone that I built, and one of the things we want to do is to integrate with a special piece of local hardware.

I am able to communicate with this hardware, building my own C++ app on the computer connected to it, but the web app being cloud based, I need some way to utilise a local executable/binary on specific machines.

Is there a method that will allow me to run an executable/binary/(custom)sdk from the browser, when available?

*I'm thinking something like Flash did with a browser plugin.  I don't mind installing and enabling permissions on the browser on these computers, as I am expecting it.*

---

**EDIT**:

Seems there was NPAPI, which was depreciated and now there's NaCL, which will be depreciated too in Q1 2018 in favour of Extensions (simple webpages).

What I will be needing is the ability to connect to a local device via some TCP/UDP socket.  Does anyone know if Extensions have available API's to access Sockets (not WebSockets, as these work differently).

Comment: forgot to mention, I finally am not restricted by browser and such, only that the machine is a windows machine (uses a COM+) element....*sigh*....nothings perfect.  :)

Comment: Been looking up Native Client (NaCL), but alas, Chrome will be depreciating it (except in ChromeOS) at the start of next year.   :(

Comment: Google Chrome now supports [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/) instead of Native Client.

Comment: Thanks Mr Anderson, interesting and might have served the purpose.  No longer working on the project but good to know for future projects.   The docs are not very clear, but the nugget that gave it away was the `path` and `type` properties in the manifest file.  :)